# How can I move between 2 gps points at a set speed?

Tags: go, gps

I'm trying to create a function that will let me give 2 arguments, a new location and a speed to travel at (in meters / second)

It looks like this:

```
func (l *Location) Move(newLoc *Location, speed float64) {
    R := 6371.0 // Kilometers
    lat1 := l.Latitude * math.Pi / 180
    lat2 := l.Longitude * math.Pi / 180
    diffLat := (newLoc.Latitude - l.Latitude) * math.Pi / 180
    diffLon := (newLoc.Longitude - l.Longitude) * math.Pi / 180

    a := math.Sin(diffLat/2)*math.Sin(diffLat/2) +
        math.Cos(lat1)*math.Cos(lat2)*math.Sin(diffLon/2)*math.Sin(diffLon/2)
    c := 2 * math.Atan2(math.Sqrt(a), math.Sqrt(1-a))

    distanceToMove := R * c // Distance to travel in a straight line, in Kilometers


}
```

The only thing I'm having trouble with is thinking of the formula to make the latitude, start at its current position, and end up at its new position over a set amount of time.

So say the person changed the latitude from `56.65` to `58.12` and I told it to travel at `1.3m/s` how can I accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is this method supposed to do? What are desired result/side effects of the function?

Comment: @Nebril the function is basically supposed to move the gps coordinates incrementally from the one spot to another, whether it has to do it in a loop or some other way I can't figure out the formula or method to get it to accomplish that

Comment: you should probably provide third parameter to Move, which would tell the function the time frame in which the location is changed.

Also the return value should probably be new Location structure, which will contain the location in which the object travelling from `l` to `newLoc` with `speed` is after time specified in new function argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your goal is to compute all the intermediate points between two location, starting from one location and going to the second one using a specified speed.

If I'm correct, the following is how I would get a first solution. If anyone can improve this, I'd appreciate.

[On the proj4 documentation](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GeodesicCalculations), you can find a lot of information on how to compute distance between two points.

Starting from points A to reach B with a given speed (m/s), just means to compute each seconds a point A' that is at a distance m from A on the line AB.

In a more algorithmic way (based on [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae)):

```
func (l *Location) Move(newLoc *Location, speed float64) Location {
    azimuthA, azimuthB, d := inverseVincenty(l, newLoc)

    // Use the direct vincenty's formula.
    // Here transform speed to get the correct value
    // without transformation, since speed is in m/s,
    // the resulting point will be at speed(m) distance from l.
    res := directVincenty(l, speed, azimuthA)

    // Now res shall contain your new point.
    return res
}

func main() {
    // init A and B and speed values.
    C := A // to conserve A position.
    t := time.Tick(1* time.Second)
    for stop := false; !stop; {
        select {
            case <- t:
            C = C.Move(B, speed)
            case // here a break condition:
                stop = true
        }
    }
}
```

I think thats a start, any comment is appreciate on this answer.